# Unhandled Rejection(Type error):Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, dependencies, components, typeerror

I have a react application. I downloaded it from one source and its not getting run on my local

I have already used "npm install" and "npm start" in my root directory. After start the application appear for 2-3 sections and the error message comes.
[image]

Comment: These are just warnings, for example: if you open the file `PhoneDirectory.js` you will see that on Line 1 `Component` is imported (or initialised as a variable in some way), but it then isn't used. This warning is to tell you about code that could be improved or deleted as it isn't needed. The error for "failed to fetch" is different, and you should update your question to include information relating to that error